# Voltage gain, input/output impedance using multisim.. How?

Tags: amplifier, ac, multisim, small-signal

[image]

This is the picture of my amplifier circuit using multisim... But I'm not very familiar with this software and thus... how do I do the AC analysis to get the voltage gain, input/output impedance...?

Comment: Is that one of those \$\pm 2\:\text{ppm}\$ resistors up there as \$R_2\$? (And I don't mean  \$\pm 2\:\frac{\text{ppm}}{^\circ\text{C}}\$.) Please do let me know the source. I've been looking for one or two. I don't use Multisim, though. So not much help there with the menu system. \$C_3\$ does look like an odd load. Intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use Multisim, but it's easy to find an amplifier's voltage gain and input and output impedances with the [CircuitLab circuit simulator](https://www.circuitlab.com/).

### Voltage Gain

I've quickly drawn your circuit and set it up to get the Bode plot of voltage gain, setting up a frequency domain simulation with `V1` as the source and `DB(MAG(V(out)))` and `PHDEG(V(out))` as the plot outputs:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTQjGI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you open the circuit above and run the simulation, you'll get the following Bode Plot showing approximately +30 dB of gain in the pass band:

[image: bode plot of voltage gain]

(If you need to recreate this on your own, there's a step-by-step tutorial on how to draw a circuit and get the voltage gain Bode Plot [here](https://www.circuitlab.com/docs/academy-bodeplot/).)

### Input Impedance

Input impedance is easy: we can just take the same circuit above and instead plot the [expression](https://www.circuitlab.com/docs/expressions/) `MAG(V(V1.nA)/I(V1.nA))`, which looks at the small-signal current relative to the small-signal voltage on source V1 and plots their ratio, an impedance.

In this case, by mousing over the plot, you'll find that it's about \$2 \ \text{k}\Omega\$ in the pass band:

[image: amplifier input impedance]

### Output Impedance

For output impedance, we need to modify the circuit slightly, just by adding a test current source connected to the output. We'll set this current source to have `0` current at DC so that it's only being used as a small-signal current source, pushing and pulling current from the output node. And then we'll plot `MAG(V(I1.nA)/I(I1.nA))` to see the output impedance:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl7RjW.png)</sup>

If you run this simulation, you'll get this plot for output impedance:

[image: output impedance plot]

The output impedance is about \$800 \ \Omega\$.

(There's a step-by-step tutorial on how to get input and output impedances [here](https://www.circuitlab.com/docs/academy-impedance/).)

Comment: Thanks! I had just found out on how to simulate it using Multisim and it is verified with your simulation! Very much appreciated